# How do I graph a hemisphere on top of a cone using ContourPlot3D?

Tags: plotting

I've figured out how to do this using RegionPlot3D, but it looks terrible.

Comment: can you provide an example of what you did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, 
             Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] == (1 - z)}, 
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 Mesh -> None, 
 BoxRatios -> {1,1,1/2},
 Boxed -> False,
 Axes -> None,
 ContourStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5]], 
                  Directive[Blue, Opacity[1]]}]
```

[image]

It is easier with `ParametricPlot3D`:

```
sp = ParametricPlot3D[
  {Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]},
  {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, 0, π/2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
  Mesh -> None, 
  Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> None];

cn = ParametricPlot3D[
  {(1 - v) Cos[u] , (1 - v) Sin[u] , v},
  {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.5]}, 
  Mesh -> None, 
  Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> None];

Show[{sp, cn}]
```

Comment: Is it possible to use inequalities with ParametricPlot3D and ContourPlot3D? Every time I attempt to do graph an inequality as opposed to a simple equals both just return the input I entered and not a graphic.

Comment: No.  A contour plot takes a function and puts a surface where the equation holds.  It creates a *contour* while an inequality would produce a *volume*.  Just imagine $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1$... gives *all* points within a sphere... not just the surface.